# onActivityResult() will not be called if call for camera

Tags: android

My simple structure:

- List.java (Activity A)
- New.java  (Activity B)

Steps:

1. Start A and use `startActivityForResult()` to turn to B by a button.
2. Then in B, use `Intent it = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);` and `startActivityForResult()` to take a photo by call up camera.
3. After that, `onActivityResult()` in B is called. Then I click a button to set a resultcode and close B.

However, B is closed, but `onActivityResult()` in A is never called.

If I skip the step to take a photo, click a button to set a resultcode and close B. `onActivityResult()` in A will be successfully called.

I'm just confused about these two situations. Please anyone tell me why the first situation happens?

Thank you very much.

Comment: I just found: A is destroyed by OS.

Comment: Please put this as answer and accept it. So that this question would not stay unanswered.

Comment: This behavior is so frustrating! onActivityResult() is called on my Android 2.3.3 and not called on Android 3.2

Comment: Just Check Your Manifest File Whether you may mistakenly written following statement android:launchmode="singleInstance" for the Activity A

Comment: i also got the same issue,there is some bug in mobile camera app because every time u done some camera work your activity is destroyed by os and when i test my app in few different company divices same code works fine with no problem and after i update my device firmware\ it works fine as well .so may be this is your problem.

Answer (score 0):

its happened when your first Activity would be destroy..

Answer (score 0):

I tried to replicate what you are describing but with no luck:

http://androidgecko.com/project.zip

Have a look and tell me if I missed something.

Know that when another application is going to the front (camera in this case) android might kill previous processes to free memory (not even activities as google docs describe, but whole PID) which might cause your problems.

I have seen this behaviour especially on older phones when you launch Gallery or Camera applications from your application.

This is one of the reasons why Applications like Facebook have their own implementation of Gallery/Camera (so that PID is not killed because its the front one).

However.. even if PID is killed what you should see is Activity recreation, meaning its `onCreate` with `savedInstanceState` not being null should fire.. and then `onActivityResult`..

check out my example and let me know how I could reproduce your issue.